# Regular expression get only one match

Tags: regex

I have problem with regular expression.

https://regexr.com/505i2

Somehow it find only one `:heart:` but it should find these words when it's beetwen `:` character.
So in this case it should be: `:heart: ,  :smile: , :smile: , :heart:`

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing the `global` flag:

```
/\:([a-zA-Z]+\w)\:/g
```

You can just tick it from the `flags` button.

The `global` flag means that you want to mark all occurrences of your pattern. Without it, you just get the first match.

Comment: Well, it works in regexr.com but not in php. What's wrong?
```
        $icon_pattern = "/:([a-zA-Z]+\w):/g/";
        preg_match_all($icon_pattern, $message, $matches);
```

Comment: @Marp You have an extra `/` use `/:([a-zA-Z]+\w):/g`

Comment: @Marp Just checked, `preg_match_all` doesn't need `global` flag, just use your usual pattern `/\:([a-zA-Z]+\w)\:/`

Comment: It work's now. Thank you! 
https://3v4l.org/G0oZG